# Highcharts - how to have a chart with dynamic height?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to have a chart that resizes with the browser window, but the problem is that the height is fixed to 400px. [This JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/yPLjR/) has the same problem.

How can I do that? I tried using the chart.events.redraw event handler to resize the chart (using .setSize), but I guess it starts a never-ending loop (fire event handler, which calls setSize, which fires another event handler, etc.).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just don't set the height property in HighCharts and it will handle it dynamically for you so long as you set a height on the chart's containing element. It can be a fixed number or a even a percent if position is absolute.

[Highcharts docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.height):

> By default the height is calculated from the offset height of the
>   containing element

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wkkAd/149/

```
#container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this with a bar chart? it's not working. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a40a0bjy/

Comment: I noticed that thanks. What I am really trying to do is to have the chart grow as it has data. With mt demo if I have one bar, it expands it to a huge bar and if I have 100 bars they are all squished together. I want to to make the page grow and keep the padding between each bar. here is my question with no response yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868963/highcharts-bar-chart-auto-height

Comment: If you aren't doing the position absolute, but just setting the height on a containing div (via css), do you need the height: 100%; width: 100% styles on an inside container?  I have something like this <div style="height: 350px;"><div class="chartContainer">{chart rendered in here}</div></div>  If I don't set 100%/100% on the chartContainer, the HighCharts doesn't seem to obey and overflows.  http://jsfiddle.net/wkkAd/446/

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect in my experience. Setting the width to null in highcharts will only cause the initial size to match the container but does not lead to responsive behavior.

Answer (score 25):

What if you hooked the window resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function() 
{    
    chart.setSize(
       $(document).width(), 
       $(document).height()/2,
       false
    );   
});
```

See example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vCZ8V/220/).

Highcharts API Reference : [setSize()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize%28%29).

Comment: I guess this works but it fails for the width of the chart if it's different than 100%. See this changed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DdtsD/

Comment: @duality_, it works for the width if you set the chart reflow option to false.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/6MnFA/

Comment: This should be debounced. Also, it's unnecessary: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.height

Answer (score 5):

When using percentage, the height it relative to the width and will dynamically change along with it:

```
chart: {
    height: (9 / 16 * 100) + '%' // 16:9 ratio
},
```

[JSFiddle Highcharts with percentage height](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/height-percent/)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the height will fix your problem because highchart is responsive by design if you adjust your screen it will also re-size.

Comment: Only on initial load, it will not be responsive.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can directly use javascript's window.onresize

As example, my code (using scriptaculos) is :

```
window.onresize = function (){
    var w = $("form").getWidth() + "px";
    $('gfx').setStyle( { width : w } );
}
```

Where form is an html form on my webpage and gfx the highchart graphics.

Answer (score 3):

Another good option is, to pass a renderTo HTML reference.
If it is a string, the element by that id is used.
Otherwise you can do:

```
chart: {
    renderTo: document.getElementById('container')
},
```

or with jquery:

```
chart: {
    renderTo: $('#container')[0]
},
```

Further information can be found here:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.renderTo

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:absolute"></div>
```

The chart fits perfect to the browser even if I resize it. You can change the percentage according to your needs.