# (kendoUI chart) Possible to reflow its size with a resizing window?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, kendo-ui

Here is the settings of the pie chart:

```
function createChart(chartDataSource) {
    $("#chart").kendoChart({
        theme:$(document).data("kendoSkin") || "black",
        title:{
            text:"Efficiency"
        },
        legend:{
            position:"bottom"
        },
        dataSource:chartDataSource,
        series:[
            {
                type:"pie",
                field:"val",
                categoryField:"status"
            }
        ],
        tooltip:{
            visible:true,
            template:"${category} - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage)#"
        }
    });
```

CSS style:

```
#chart {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    }
```

I know that Highcharts has `reflow` boolean ([reflow example in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809852/highcharts-how-to-have-a-chart-with-dynamic-height)) did exactly what I want.

I am not sure whether kendoUI chart have the same reflow setting or I should play around with the CSS style. If go for CSS, how to make such setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Applying my idea in your linked post, just hook the window resize event and redraw the chart:

```
$(window).resize(function() 
{    
    var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
    chart.refresh();
});
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/neCLb/).

Comment: Thanks, I've been thinking about using refresh to update the chart, is it the only way to handle this? Or some CSS code can be applied to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Mark thank you very much. If you have time please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371374/chart-rendering-issue-with-resizing-div-container), I've been trying to fix for long time.

Comment: $(window).resize(function(){ kendo.resize($(".k-chart")); }); will do the job without refreshing the chart.