# Chart rendering issue with resizing <div> container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, highcharts

I have **two** question for chart rendering when its container is resized.

**First** thing is, how to render chart correctly when its container is resized..

i.e. Maximize / Restore problem, at its first rendering it works just fine, however when I restore the size of the window, the charts begin to overlay as its previous size. As you can see from the following pics: 
 [image][image]

I know if you set a resize handler (and wait a small amount of time) to refresh the chart whenever the window is resized, the problem can be solved. I am thinking whether there are some other approaches to let the chart flow to the right size without refreshing the chart every time.

The **second** thing is:
If the charting area is in a `<div>` container, and the size of the container will change with a resize bar. I use the following code to get it work with the window resizing. But it **won't** work with a moving resize bar.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            createChart(chartData);
        }, 300);
    });
```

**Note**: The grid component works just fine in any case and just the chart I am always having troubles. 
I am using HighCharts, kendoUI grid and both of them are rendered in jQueryUI portlets.

Any comments appreciated!This problem has taken me a long time..

**Update:** Since I think my explanation of the issue is not clear enough, I added [**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jxTUw/) for better understanding. Basically I want two things: 1. reflow the size of the chart to fit its container when window is resizing; 2. reflow the size of chart to fit its container when the resize bar is moving.

I am using plugins [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) for charting, [jQuery UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) for layout management in this example. For some other plugins I am using, please refer to [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378324/is-it-recommended-to-use-a-lot-of-jquery-plugins-in-your-project), I am not sure whether they have conflicts.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your code at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with a JSFiddle example. Please take a look at my update. Thank you!

Comment: HMMmmm see if this will give you some ideas [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxTUw/1/) another recommendation is tagging this to the jqueryUI and css guys

Comment: Its still not working very well, but thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe what you want can be accomplished without hooking the resize event and redrawing the chart.

To solve your "div" resize problem, look at something like [this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) which allows you to bind the resize event to things other than the window (it your case your "container" div).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxTUw/4/) of it in action.

Comment: Great Answer, exactly what I want, reflow the size of the container without reload the chart. Thanks Mark.

Comment: For performance, in your scenario you should set `reflow` to false on the chart, as i've explained over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768565/resize-height-with-highcharts/15076588#15076588

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and solved it doing the following:

When defining the resizable div that will contain the higcharts chart:

```
        $("#container").resizable({
            resize: function (event, ui) {
                var delay = 1000;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(window).resize();
                }, delay);
            }
        });
```

And inside the definition of the chart:

```
           var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
           .........
            $(window).resize(function() {
                chart.reflow();
           ..........
            });
```

So basically, you are resizing the window with a delay. Not very elegant, but works fine for me.