# Resize height with Highcharts

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts

I have a Highchart which resizes the width beatuifully when the window change size. But not the height. I tried this set chart size but it's not working proberly. Is there any other way to automatically change the height when window change size?

This is my css code for the output. I have a Jquery UI tab, the other tab is showing the datatable

```
#output-container
{
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px; 
    left: 400px;
    top:120px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This is my css for the chartdiv:

```
#chartContainer{
    margin: auto;
}
```

And this is the js Chart function:

```
function qchart(){
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chartContainer',
            type: 'column',
            spacingBottom: 3,
            //height: (screen.availHeight)-500,
            marginRight: 30,
            marginBottom: 30,
            reflow: true
        },
        //etc..
    };
    //...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highcharts - how to have a chart with dynamic height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809852/highcharts-how-to-have-a-chart-with-dynamic-height)

Comment: For adjust hidden charts and on risize window
[See my stackoverflow answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216722/highcharts-hidden-charts-dont-get-re-size-properly/25083192#25083192

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Ricardo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13769118/7032856) is correct, however: sometimes you may find yourself in a situation where the container simply doesn't resize as desired as the browser window changes size, thus not allowing highcharts to resize itself.

This always works:

1. Set up a timed and pipelined resize event listener. [Example with
   500ms on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/c9UE5/5/)
2. use [`chart.setSize(width, height, doAnimation =
   true);`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize%28%29)
   in your actual resize function to set the height and width
   dynamically
3. Set `reflow: false` in the highcharts-options and of course set `height` and `width` explicitly on creation. As we'll be doing our own resize event handling there's no need Highcharts hooks in another one.

Comment: I'm quite new to high charts and jQuery / javascript, can you give a code sample for me to follow?

Answer (score 17):

According to the API Reference:

`By default the height is calculated from the offset height of the containing element. Defaults to null.`

So, you can control it's `height` according to the parent div using `redraw` event, which is called when it changes it's size.

*References*

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.height
- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.events.redraw

Comment: Sincerest apologies - i have just retested this and it looks if you properly resize the immediate parent container it actually works. Cannot take back my downvote (system says "vote is now locked unless the post is edited"), if you edit a line or two i'll surely take it back.

Answer (score 14):

You must set the height of the container explicitly

```
#container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute; 
}
```

[See other Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809852/highcharts-how-to-have-a-chart-with-dynamic-height)

[Highcharts documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with height except my chart was inside a bootstrap modal popup, which I'm already controlling the size of with css.  However, for some reason when the window was resized horizontally the height of the chart container would expand indefinitely.  If you were to drag the window back and forth it would expand vertically indefinitely.  I also don't like hard-coded height/width solutions.

So, if you're doing this in a modal, combine [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25400458/350270)  with a window resize event.

```
// from link
$('#ChartModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $('.chart-container').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});

$('#ChartModal').on('shown.bs.modal.', function() {
    $('.chart-container').css('visibility', 'initial');
    $('#chartbox').highcharts().reflow()
    //added
    ratio = $('.chart-container').width() / $('.chart-container').height();
});
```

Where "ratio" becomes a height/width aspect ratio, that will you resize when the bootstrap modal resizes.  This measurement is only taken when he modal is opened.  I'm storing ratio as a global but that's probably not best practice.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    //chart-container is only visible when the modal is visible.
    if ( $('.chart-container').is(':visible') ) {
        $('#chartbox').highcharts().setSize( 
            $('.chart-container').width(),
            ($('.chart-container').width() / ratio),
            doAnimation = true );
    }       
});
```

So with this, you can drag your screen to the side (resizing it) and your chart will maintain its aspect ratio.

Widescreen

[image]

vs smaller

[image]

(still fiddling around with vw units, so everything in the back is too small to read lol!)