# Reactjs - functional HOC to re-render on browser resize?

Tags: reactjs

Over on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014250/reactjs-rerender-on-browser-resize/31560116#31560116), it is answered how to bind a component to browser resize events. I'd like to create an HOC/decorator function to elegantly add this behaviour to Components in my Component Library so that I can be dry about adding this behaviour.

I was able to use the inverted HOC pattern to create a higher-order-component that will essentially attach the base components `onResize` method to a (resize) event listener:

```
import React from 'react';
import debounce from 'debounce';
import getDisplayName from 'recompose/getDisplayName'

export const withOnResize = BaseComponent => (
  class ResizeEnhanced extends BaseComponent {
    static displayName = getDisplayName(BaseComponent);

    componentWillMount() {
      this.debounce = debounce(this.onResize, 200);
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.debounce);
      if (super.componentWillMount) super.componentWillMount();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.debounce);
      if (super.componentWillUnmount) super.componentWillUnmount();
    }

    render() {
      return super.render();
    }
  }
);
```

and then the usage in some other component file:

```
export default withOnResize(MyComponent); // MyComponent has an onResize method.
```

--

This is sub-optimal at least because there is a dodgy reliance on the base component having an onResize method.

Is there a functional approach that would allow easily connecting resize listener and lifecycle events to a method on base components?

Obviously another option is to use something like Redux, and build the global events into the store - dispatching as required. Or even context if I was willing to re-render my entire app on context change, but I'm more interested in doing this at the component decoration level at this stage.

Comment: Interesting question, but not quite sure what you're looking for. You just want to call an arbitrary method on the component, rather than the hard coded `onResize`?

Comment: Right. I suppose what I'd like is for the base component to be able to subscribe to the HOC event emission, in a sort of listener pattern, i.e. passing back the handler (re-rendering being one handler option), rather than passing back the event. Is this inherently wrong to ask?

Comment: The more I think about it, I don't see why just passing a prop, and letting that prop change be the trigger isn't the obvious solution. So the HOC simply adds listeners, and adds a prop to the child element that is some result of those listeners. The child element re-renders when the prop changes. Done.