# Is the `window` object of React synthetic?

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering if the `window` object that is passed into react components synthetic or not.

If it isn't I am presuming I would need the following code to determine the width and height of the viewport

```
const w = window,
  d = document,
  documentElement = d.documentElement,
  body = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
  width = w.innerWidth || documentElement.clientWidth || body.clientWidth,
  height = w.innerHeight || documentElement.clientHeight || body.clientHeight
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `window` object is the normal DOM object.

It is always available and safe to use (unless you are server side rendering).

Comment: you may want to change the method name I think it starts with small `c`

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano Oops.  Updated.

Comment: Also you noted that it is when it is mounted, but that would contradict http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014250/reactjs-rerender-on-browser-resize

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano Can you be more specific?

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano If you are implying that you can access the DOM in `componentWillMount`, it does appear that way in the answers to the above linked SO question, but the docs (linked above) make it clear that this should be done in `componentDidMount`. Using `componentWillMount` may be safe for non root components, but I don't think it would work on the root component itself. Only one way to find out =)

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano After testing this, it seems that `window` is available in `componentWillMount`.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I did test it actually and it was working but I wanted to confirm as well because your original answer threw me off a bit.

Answer (score 9):

Accessing the window object in React is the same as anywhere else. It exists before any of your JavaScript runs. As a test, type about:blank into your location bar, open the console and type 'window'.  It's there even with no other JavaScript on the page.