# How to re-render components everytime state is set

Tags: redux, store, immutable.js

I want my components to re-render everytime I call 'state.set(...)', **even if the values doesn't change.**

So hey guys, i have this reducer, which is called everytime screen is resized:

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';

const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  width: ''
});     

 export default (state=initialState, action) => {
        switch(action.type){    
          case "SCREEN_RESIZE":            
            if(action.payload >= 768){
              return state.set('width', 'big');
            }
            else{
              return state.set('width', 'small');
            }    
          default:
          break;
      }
      return state;
    }
```

I'm using ImmutableJS along with redux, so my store is a map (entire store) of maps (each reducer).

The problem is that my components only re-renders when we change 'width' from 'big' to 'small', or from 'small' to 'big', that is, when value changes!

I  want it to re-render even when I set width from 'big' to 'big' or from 'small' to 'small'.

Am I making any mistake?

This is my rootReducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';

import reducer1 from './reducer1_reducer';
import reducer2 from './reducer2_reducer';
import reducer3 from './reducer3_reducer';
import screenSize from './screenSize_reducer';
import reducer5 from './reducer5_reducer';
import rounting from './routerReducer';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  reducer1,
  reducer2,
  reducer3,
  screenSize,
  reducer5,
  routing
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: In React, rendering is coupled tightly to state changes. Any particular reason you want to render despite the state remaining the same? Are you trying to re-render due to change in viewport/screen size?

Comment: exactly. there's a component that, when rendering, calculates it dimensions according to window size. so if it not re-renders, it remains the same.

Comment: Set the value of the width in your reducer and use a selector for computing `big`/`small`. It's never a good idea to keep derivative data in the state of the redux store.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-render on each screen-resizing, you're probably going to want to make the props of the component have the actual screen dimensions, like so:

```
<MyRerenderableComp width={this.props.screenWidth} height={this.props.screenHeight} />
```

You're question is somewhat similar to this post: [Reactjs - Rerender on browser resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014250/reactjs-rerender-on-browser-resize)

Hope that helps?