# How to changing layout based on screen size with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design

I want to be able to change my layout when i hit a given screen size so i can change the way my site looks when it hits a mobile view.

Currently my react site scrolls horizontally using the package [Horitzontal Scroll Package](http://hew.github.io/react-scroll-horizontal/)

I've tried implementing this with the react-responsive package which allows me to run media queries but there seems to be a conflict between the two packages.

So i want my site to scroll horizontal when in full screen (Desktop and table) and then scroll top to bottom in mobile view. How would i do this?

```
class Home extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        home: projectsData.filter( p => p.name === "homepage" ),
        galleryImages: [
            ImgOne,
            ImgTwo,
            ImgThree,
            ImgFour,
            ImgFive,
            ImgSix
        ]
    });
}

render(){

    const test = { color: "black", position: "fixed" }
    return(
        <div className="row">
            <Responsive minWidth={992}>
                <HorizontalScroll reverseScroll={true}>
                    <Header />
                    <SplashScreen />
                    <CopyText />
                </HorizontalScroll>
            </Responsive>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

NOTE: I know that the horizontal-scroll package doesn't support sizing with percentages.

Comment: Maybe you could do some work in componentDidMount as in these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014250/reactjs-rerender-on-browser-resize

Answer (score 5):

[You can use Material UI `<Hidden>` component.](https://material-ui.com/layout/hidden/#hidden)
Deprecated in Version5 of Material Ui. [sx](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/) prop replaced it

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import withWidth from '@material-ui/core/withWidth';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    flex: '1 0 auto',
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

function BreakpointUp(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography variant="subtitle1">Current width: {props.width}</Typography>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Hidden xsUp>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xsUp</Paper>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden smUp>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>smUp</Paper>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden mdUp>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>mdUp</Paper>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden lgUp>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>lgUp</Paper>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden xlUp>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xlUp</Paper>
        </Hidden>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

BreakpointUp.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  width: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default compose(
  withStyles(styles),
  withWidth(),
)(BreakpointUp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the HorizontalScroll component, but I can give you a code example of how to change layout based on screen size with React.

```
class WindowWidth extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.onResize = this.onResize.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.children({ width: this.state.width });
  }
  getWindowWidth() {
    return Math.max(
      document.documentElement.clientWidth,
      window.innerWidth || 0
    );
  }
  onResize() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.setState({
        width: this.getWindowWidth()
      });
    });
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      width: this.getWindowWidth()
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
  }
}

const Vertical = props => <div> Vertical component: {props.children}</div>;
const Horizontal = props => <div> Horizontal component: {props.children}</div>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <WindowWidth>
    {({ width }) => {
      if (width >= 992) {
        return <Horizontal>{width}px</Horizontal>;
      }
      return <Vertical>{width}px</Vertical>;
    }}
  </WindowWidth>,
  document.querySelector("#react-app")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into Media Queries. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KL-z9A56SQ&feature=youtu.be) is a short video to show you the basics.

You can set a threshold that will trigger separate styles under those conditions. It can be very useful when you want your UI to do something different at different sizes.

```
@media only screen 
and (*Your threshold criteria goes here* EXAMPLE:  max-width : 1000px) {   
  //css goes here with whatever css you want to fire at this threshold
}
```

Comment: This will apply new CSS, but if he wants a completely different DOM, this won't get him very far.