# React accessing state before ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

When I try to access a state variable which is set in `ComponentDidMount`, react throws an undefined error. This is because I believe when I'm calling the fetch `api` and `setState` in `ComponentDidMount`, the value isn't ready yet (`async` stuff). Is there a proper way to either delay the render until the `setState` call is done or some other way to get the state updated fully before render is called?

Comment: You can (and should) show some loading UI until the fetch finishes. Just have the data in state with an initial value. Then when that initial value changes, switch to rendering from the fetched data

Comment: Thinking about this wrong. See https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is setState() inside componentDidMount() considered an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168047/is-setstate-inside-componentdidmount-considered-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

I think the code below will give you a basic idea how fetch data and render work.

```
class App extends Component {
    state = { 
        data:{},
        loading:true,
        error:null,
     }
     componentDidMount = () => {
        fetch('https://example.com/api/article')
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((json) => {
          this.setState({
            data:json,
            loading:false,    
          }) 
          .catch(error => {
            this.setState({
                error,
                loading:false,
              })  
          });
        });

     }

    render() {
        const {data,error,loading} = this.state;
        if(loading){
            return "Loading ..."
        }
        if(error){
            return "Something went wrong."
        }
        return 'your actual render component or data';
    }
}

export default App;
```