# Lifecycle hooks - Where to set state?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add sorting to my movie app, I had a code that was working fine but there was too much code repetition, I would like to take a different approach and keep my code DRY. Anyways, I am confused as on which method should I set the state when I make my AJAX call and update it with a click event.

This is a module to get the data that I need for my app.

```
export const moviesData = {
  popular_movies: [],
  top_movies: [],
  theaters_movies: []
};

export const queries = {
  popular:
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=###&page=",
  top_rated:
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=###&page=",
  theaters:
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=###&page="
};

export const key = "68f7e49d39fd0c0a1dd9bd094d9a8c75";

export function getData(arr, str) {
  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    moviesData[arr].push(str + i);
  }
}
```

The stateful component:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { 
   movies = [],
   sortMovies: "popular_movies",
   query: queries.popular,
   sortValue: "Popularity"
  }
}

// Here I am making the http request, documentation says
// this is a good place to load data from an end point
async componentDidMount() {
    const { sortMovies, query } = this.state;
    getData(sortMovies, query);

    const data = await Promise.all(
      moviesData[sortMovies].map(async movie => await axios.get(movie))
    );
    const movies = [].concat.apply([], data.map(movie => movie.data.results));

    this.setState({ movies });
  }
```

In my app I have a dropdown menu where you can sort movies by popularity, rating, etc. I have a method that when I select one of the options from the dropwdown, I update some of the states properties:

```
handleSortValue = value => {
    let { sortMovies, query } = this.state;

    if (value === "Top Rated") {
      sortMovies = "top_movies";
      query = queries.top_rated;
    } else if (value === "Now Playing") {
      sortMovies = "theaters_movies";
      query = queries.theaters;
    } else {
      sortMovies = "popular_movies";
      query = queries.popular;
    }

    this.setState({ sortMovies, query, sortValue: value });
  };
```

Now, this method works and it is changing the properties in the state, but my components are not re-rendering. I still see the movies sorted by popularity since that is the original setup in the state (sortMovies), nothing is updating.

I know this is happening because I set the state of movies in the `componentDidMount` method, but I need data to be Initialized by default, so I don't know where else I should do this if not in this method.

I hope that I made myself clear of what I am trying to do here, if not please ask, I'm stuck here and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The best lifecycle method for fetching data is `componentDidMount()`. According to [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#how-can-i-make-an-ajax-call):

> **Where in the component lifecycle should I make an AJAX call?**
>
> You should populate data with AJAX calls in the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method. This is so you can use `setState()` to update your component when the data is retrieved.

Example code from the docs:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.name}>
              {item.name} {item.price}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**Bonus:** `setState()` inside `componentDidMount()` is considered an anti-pattern. Only use this pattern when fetching data/measuring DOM nodes.
Further reading:

- [HashNode discussion](https://hashnode.com/post/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-call-setstate-immediately-after-componentdidmount-in-react-cim5vz8kn01flek53aqa22mby)
- [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168047/is-setstate-inside-componentdidmount-considered-an-anti-pattern/52168388)