# Way to access axios response data outside/ global

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

this is my first time to develop a react application.

I will be using the get response of axios to populate a table. The outside var is declared and used outside the scope of the axios, and when I update that var inside the scope of axios, it does not update the var data outside, as per checking in debug.

Is there a way to use the get response of axios outside/ in global scope?

Thank you very much for your help.

```
//rows is declared outside the scope
let rows = [];

  axios
    .get(`url here`)
    .then(res => {
      for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
        //rows.push not reflecting on the react application (inside scope of res)
        rows.push(res.data[i]);
      }
    });

  //rows.push reflecting on the react application (outside scope of res)
  rows.push({
    test: 5.7
  });
```

Comment: As long as you are accessing `rows` after your asynchronous request has completed, your code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

## Use async functions

If you want code to run in an async way you need to use the `async` keyword and use `await` to wait for promises to be resolved.

### Example

```
async function getData() {
  const rows = [];
  const res = await axios.get('url here');
  for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
    rows.push(res.data[i]);
  }
  rows.push({
    test: 5.7,
  });
}
```

### Explanation

In your code the line with `let rows = [];` runs and then `axios.get(...` starts. then since the code is waiting for a promise it continues with `rows.push({test: 5.7});` until the data is returned in the `then`

In my example each line runs when the previous is finished because we wait for data to return from the promise. It becomes easier to read. But be aware that the function `getData` now returns a promise. So anywhere that invokes the function `getData` will also have to await its response.

## In React

If you're retrieving data in react there are some things you should know. If the first is, if the data is needed on load then put the request into the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

you will have to make it async though.

### Example

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const data = await getData();
  this.setState({data});
}
```

This will cause an additional render when the component loads. There some more info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52168388/2504407).

Alternatively you may want to get data with a state management library like `Redux`. In `Redux` you can use actions to get your data so that this process is removed from individual components and more easily shared between them via the library `react-redux` and the connect decorator.