# CONSOLE.LOG div attributes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, game-development

So I have the following div.

[image]

On google chrome I can inspect the element and see the size of the div. How can I capture the size of this div and store it as a variable? I'm assuming this can dynamically change depending on the users platform.

I need the current size of the div to create a ping pong type floating ball contained in the size of that div.

Comment: This might be what you need: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS - Get Height of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153599/reactjs-get-height-of-an-element)

Comment: Since you tagged the question with React, a mix of `getBoundingClientRect`, and React's refs should be enough. Se also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49058890/1218980

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), which gives you the bounding box values for any element in the DOM.

Comment: I think the most important part is capturing componentDidMount first.

Comment: That is somewhat of a given though, as any DOM operations can only happen after mounting has occurred. There is no DOM to analyse before then.