# How to handle error - "Failed to fetch" in a React app at codesandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codesandbox

I am building a custom event calendar `Component` for my Yoga `App` on `codesandbox`. Actually I was going to do it on my `IDE`, but the think started to pick up pretty fast and I ended up using it.

I was trying to get the `width` and `height` from a `<div/>` using `ref={(el) => this.props.testing((this.container = el))` then trying to access the dims on `componentDidMount()`, pretty much like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058890/how-to-get-a-react-components-size-height-width-before-render/49058984) solution.

Suddenly I started getting the following error on `codesandbox`:

```
TypeError

Failed to fetch

This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
This error overlay is powered by `react-error-overlay` used in `create-react-app`.
```

and on the console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

(index):1 Access to fetch at 'https://codesandbox.io/api/v1/sandboxes/wm1dl/cache' from origin
'https://wm1dl.codesandbox.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors'
to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

codesandbox.io/api/v1/sandboxes/wm1dl/cache:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

I tried inspecting my network, and other stuff, but I don't know how to normalize this.

I need to normalize this, or be at least able to ensure that I could safely copy/commit my files to github then use it on my IDE.

here is my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/continuing-my-agenda-wm1dl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: I tried the cache, memory, but it could not help at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparantly a lot of us are getting this issue. this should go away eventually..

Its not a Blocker though. you can just close the modal. just like that

[image]

Comment: Oh so this is not on me. It's some sort of bug on codesandbox that's going on?

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks so much for the feedback. I'm relieved =)

Comment: @Alioshr.. if my answer helped u.. pls do accept it too.

Comment: tks. I still need to wait for 3 min to accept an answer =) I will accept it for sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210279/discussion-between-aliosh-r-and-barun-patro).

Answer (score 1):

This error could happen when  the codesandbox is accessed using `https` and the fetch call you are making is using `http`. Changing the fetch api call to `https` resolves this