# How to get the size (height/width) of a specific instance of a conditionally rendered list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**[QUESTION EDITED AS IT WAS NOT CLEAR ENOUGH]**

I am trying to simply get the `width` & `height` of one of the rendered `<div/>` on `Child.js`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058890/how-to-get-a-react-components-size-height-width-before-render/49058984) is a great example, but on my case I do not have jus one `<div/>`, but an `array` of `containers` dynamically rendered.

Issue:

I have restricted the number of `refs` being sent up to `App.js` as you can see on `Child.js: line 12` hopping that it would work, having a stable data being received so I could `setState` for just the `ref` of the first `<div>` being rendered at `Child.js`.

It actually works on an "apparent" first `iteration`, but then, event though I am getting `childData` from just `index 0` of `Child.js`, somehow `childData` iterates again and it becomes `null`, with the following error: `Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null`

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/stupefied-dew-0pv6z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    childDims: {
      width: "",
      heigth: ""
    }
  };

  gettingDimsFromChildDataDiv = childData => {
    const { height, width } = childData.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(`height: ${height} & width: ${width}`);
    this.setState(
      ({ childDims, ...restTop }) => ({
        childDims: {
          width,
          height
        },
        ...restTop
      }),   //It actually sets state once... But for some reason it iterates 
            //another time and childData becomes null...
      () => console.log("setting state", this.state.childDims)
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Child liftContainerDimensions={this.gettingDimsFromChildDataDiv} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import React from "react";

export default class Child extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dummyArray: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.dummyArray.map((donkey, index) => {
          let ref = null;
          //I tried to restrict the number of instances sent up to App.js
          // Hopping that it would make it possible to safely setState there
          if (index === 0) {
            ref = el =>
              this.props.liftContainerDimensions((this.container = el));
          }
          return (
            <div
              key={donkey}
              style={{ border: "1px solid red", margin: "5px" }}
              ref={ref}
            >
              {donkey}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create a ref and attach it to the child component, and then use `ref.current.getBoundingClientRect()` which will give you an object containing width and height properties of the child.

Comment: could you please illustrate @JMadelaine?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take. It feels odd but this accomplishes what you want.

https://codesandbox.io/s/get-a-react-components-size-heightwidth-before-render-for-array-of-containers-chsy6

It uses hooks so it may look a little odd to you.

Comment: I am going to reformulate the question. The solution presented had already been achieve d by me. The issue I am having is on the moment of setting state. Getting the dims is not the issue here

Comment: Why do you want it in state? You can pass down a ref. What you're trying to do can cause endless update loops.