# How do I Create a Vertical Arrow with Text Annotation with Dynamic Text Positioning in Konva?

Tags: reactjs, react-konva, konva

I'm trying to draw some geometric shapes in the user interface via Konva and react-konva. One basic element is a vertical arrow with annotated text to show the dimension of a shape, as shown below:

[image: Screenshot of Vertical Arrow]

It's created by the following code snippet, which was my first attempt at implementing it.

```
import {Stage, Layer, Group, Rect, Arrow, Text} from 'react-konva';

function AnnotatedVerticalArrow({x, y0, y1, text})
{
  return (
    <Group>
      <Arrow
        points={[x, y0, x, y1]}
        pointerAtBeginning={true}
        pointerAtEnding={true}
        fill="black"
        stroke="black"
      />  
      <Text
        x={x - 35} 
        y={(y1 - y0) / 2}
        text={text}
        fontSize={12}
      />  
    </Group>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
      <Layer>
        <AnnotatedVerticalArrow
          x={50}
          y0={0}
          y1={100}
          text="2.54"
        />
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );  
}

export default App;
```

However, I don't know how to correctly position the text, and this implementation has several problems:

1. The text label is not centered properly, as the origin of the text label is not the center of the text, but at the corner. In order to find its center, the dimension of the text is required.
2. The spacing between the arrow and the text label is hardcoded for a font with size 12. Changing font size, using shorter text, or using longer text breaks the user interface due to excessive or insufficient spacing.

How do I calculate the size of a `Text` and use its dimension during rendering?

I've seen an [extensive discussion](https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/issues/6) about text size calculation at GitHub repository konvajs/react-konva, the suggested solution is calculating the size in `componentDidMount()`, then using the size to change the state of the element and force a rerender. But the example code needs an update since it's written for React classes, not React hooks. The example is also unclear about how to calculate the dimension with different font sizes. Another proposed using `measureText`, but one commenter claimed the result was buggy. Yet another developer suggested an extremely complicated workaround, how it works is not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer by combining the [answer to the question *How to get a react component's size (height/width) before render?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058890/how-to-get-a-react-components-size-height-width-before-render) and the example code in GitHub repo *konvajs/react-konva*'s [Issue #6](https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/issues/6).

The solution is to:

1. Represent the calculated size of the text as a state, `calculatedTextSize` via `useState()`, initialize the default values to `0`.
2. Create a reference to the Text as `textRef` via `useRef()`.
3. Set the property `ref` of the Text we're returning to `textRef`, so this component is associated with the reference and becomes accessible in code.
4. Calculate the size of the Text by accessing `calculatedTextSize.width` and `calculatedTextSize.height`, as if it's already calculated.
5. Perform the size calculation in `React.useLayoutEffect()` callback. This function is executed when the first render pass is completed. Within the function, call the `measureSize()` method of the Text to obtain the result, then pass the result by changing the state via `setCalculatedTextSize()`.
6. ...which triggers a re-render, so the new size is used.

The new implementation of `AnnotatedVerticalArrow()` is:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Stage, Layer, Group, Rect, Arrow, Text} from 'react-konva';

function AnnotatedVerticalArrow({x, y0, y1, text})
{
  const textRef = React.useRef();
  const [calculatedTextSize, setCalculatedTextSize] =
    React.useState({width: 0, height: 0});

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (textRef.current) {
      setCalculatedTextSize({
        width: textRef.current.measureSize(text).width,
        height: textRef.current.measureSize(text).height
      }); 
    }   
  }, [text]);  // "text" must be inside the dependency array
               // otherwise repeated changes to its size will be ignored

  return (
    <Group>
      <Arrow
        points={[x, y0, x, y1]}
        pointerAtBeginning={true}
        pointerAtEnding={true}
        fill="black"
        stroke="black"
      />
      <Text
        ref={textRef}
        x={x - calculatedTextSize.width * 1.1}
        y={(y1 - y0) / 2 - calculatedTextSize.height / 2}
        text={text}
        fontSize={12}
      />  
    </Group>
  )
}
```

It remains working even if `fontSize` has been changed, since `textRef` is always a reference to the `Text` component that we've created in the rendering code path.