# How to do pagination like Google docs using React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

In Google Docs, if you create a document. You will start writing on Page 1. If the page is filled with content, then automatically **Page 2** is created and the rest of the content goes to page 2 and so on. If you remove some lines from Page 1, then the contents from Page 2 (If there are any) will be moved to the bottom of Page 1.

So in my scenario, I have some presentational components (Around 10) which get filled by a form. Consider Left Pane has a form and updating them shows a live preview of Docs-like UI on the right pane.

I tried directly manipulating DOM using some methods like `insertBefore` in a react app. I read that doing DOM manipulation directly on a React App is error-prone and it is not recommended. Is there any other pattern or method to achieve this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that the only to solve your problem would be to measure the size of content with `useLayoutEffect`, and then to 'split' said content into pages.

(This is because I'm assuming you don't know the size of the each item from the list - if you did it would be simpler!).

I'd start with a `useComponentSize` hook that would look something like so:

```
// Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272554/6595024


const useComponentSize = () => {
  const informParentOfHeightChange = useContext<(h: number) => void>(
    UpdateParentAboutMyHeight
  );
  const targetRef = useRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (targetRef.current) {
      informParentOfHeightChange(targetRef.current.offsetHeight);
    }

    return () => informParentOfHeightChange(0);
  }, [informParentOfHeightChange]);

  return targetRef;
};


const UpdateParentAboutMyHeight = /* Left as an exercise to the reader */
```

Note: That my implementation is rather 'basic'; you'd probably want to [useTransition](https://react.dev/reference/react/useTransition) or some other type of debounce effect so your UI wouldn't slow down to a crawl

Using this hook, the child would be able to inform the parent whenever it's height changed.
Here's an example:

```
const Comp = () => {
  const targetRef = useComponentSize();

  return <div ref={targetRef}>{/* etc */}</div>;
};
```

So then 'all' you'd need to do is create a parent component that keeps track of the height of all of it's `Comp` children.

Here's some (inefficient) pseudo code to help you get an idea:

```
const UpdateParentAboutMyHeightProvider = /* Left as an exercise to the reader */

const HEIGHT_PER_PAGE = 1000;

const PageLayout = ({ items_to_render }: { items_to_render: Comp[] }) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<{ height: number }[]>([]);

  let curHeight = 0;
  let curPage = 0;
  const pages = items_to_render.reduce((pageList, item, index) => {
    const itemHeight = items[index].height;
    if (curHeight + itemHeight >= HEIGHT_PER_PAGE) {
      // Create a new page!
      pageList.push([item]);
      curHeight = itemHeight;
      curPage += 1;
      return pageList;
    }
    // Add to existing page!
    curHeight += itemHeight;
    pageList[curPage].push(item);
    return pageList;
  }, [] as Array<Array<Comp>>);

  return (
    <UpdateParentAboutMyHeightProvider value={setItems}>
      {pages.map((page, number) => (
        <Page number={number + 1} key={number}>{page.map((item) => item)}</Page>
      ))}
    </UpdateParentAboutMyHeightProvider>
  );
};
```

I'll repeat that the implementation I wrote here is very basic and inefficient; the logic for when a page would be bigger than the maximum size is also probably insufficient[1]

Hopefully it'll be helpful in pointing you in the right direction.

[1] I kept it simple for readability and because I don't know your particular use case

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier (by Syed), you can use  Draft.js. But if you want a simple and flexible pagination component that works with any data source, why not using `react-paginate`.

To use react-paginate, you need to install it with npm:

```
npm install react-paginate
```

Then you need to import it in your React component:

```
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
```

See the example below in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-paginate-simple-and-flexible-pagination-component-zckjxk?file=/src/App.js) on "**How to use react-paginate**".