# Getting white space when i minimize the screen in chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using Chrome, my page is as expected when it is in normal mode but when I minimize screen, white space is coming at the bottom and some content is hidden, page is based of reactjs, html, css.
its working fine for IE (both Normal n Minimize)

What is the error and how can I solve this?

Comment: Make sure that this 'white space' is not an scroll. If so you would need to react on resize

Comment: please add a codesandbox link. thank

Comment: @Maciej Trojniarz  can u please elaborate, becoz its working for IE

Comment: @Xenio Gracias Dnt mine, what's that codesandbox link and how it works

Comment: @Tej check this link https://codesandbox.io/s/y2lrywpk21. you an add your code here

Comment: @Maciej Trojniarz  Yes, White space is coming in scroll where some content has to come

Comment: @Tej so then you need to work with your layout to allow scroll or to bypass it. You maybe should try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014250/rerender-view-on-browser-resize-with-react

Answer (score -1):

Not sure without looking at it. But you can try to use some kind of hack to show css border on all the elements of the document using

```
* {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Another post i read https://dev.to/gajus/my-favorite-css-hack-32g3