# React - get element.getBoundingClientRect() after window resize

Tags: reactjs

I have a class that needs to get the size of a DOM element. It works well, but when I resize the window it doesn't update until I change the state in my app, forcing a rerender. I've tried adding `this.forceUpdate` to a `'resize'` event listener in `componentDidMount()`, but it didn't work. Perhaps I did something wrong? Ideally I'd like to avoid using `this.forceUpdate` for perfomance implications anyway. Any work arounds for this? Thanks in advance!

My code:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { x: 0, y: 0 }

  refCallback = (element) => {
    if (!element) {
      return
    }
    const { x, y } = element.getBoundingClientRect()
    this.setState({ x, y })
  }

  render() {
    console.log('STATE:', this.state) // Outputs the correct x and y values.
    return (
      <div ref={this.refCallback}>
        <button>Hello world</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add a ```resize``` event listener on the ```window``` object? That's the element where a browser resize event is fired. You can see an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014250/rerender-view-on-browser-resize-with-react) of how this is done with hooks in this question, but basically the same method can be used with a class component, where you write a function that updates your state and attach it to the window.

Comment: @ChrisB. I've already given that a try

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to measure some element in your component whenever the window resizes, it's going to look something like this:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  };

  element = React.createRef();

  onWindowResize = () => {
    if (this.element.current) {
      const {x, y} = this.element.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.setState({x, y}, () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      });
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.element}>
        <button>Hello, World</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The trick here is that your `ref` callback is only called *once*, when the element is initially added to the DOM. If you want to update state whenever you resize the window, you're going to need a `'resize'` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

That happening because:

From [the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

> #### Adding a Ref to a DOM Element
>
> React supports a special attribute that you can attach to any component. The `ref` attribute takes a callback function, and the callback will be executed immediately after the component is mounted or unmounted.
>
> React will call the `ref` callback with the DOM element when the component mounts, and call it with `null` when it unmounts.

So, that's why when you refresh you get the value. To overcome the problem you can do something like this:

```
import React from "react";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };
  }

  updateDimensions = () => {
    if (this.myRef.current) {
      const {x, y} = this.myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.setState({ x, y });
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("STATE:", this.state); // Outputs the correct x and y values.
    return (
      <div ref={this.myRef}>
        <button>Hello world</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Hope this works for you.