# Setting state without re-rendering with useEffect not working

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks, setstate, use-effect

I simply need my state value to change based on screen sizing live time. Even though my screen size changes, my count value stays the same unless I reload the page. this needs to update live for better responsive design. Here is my code. Thanks!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Carousel from '@brainhubeu/react-carousel';
import '@brainhubeu/react-carousel/lib/style.css';
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive'

const MyCarousel = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        loadMediaQuery();
    }, []);

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const loadMediaQuery = () =>{
        if (tablet)
            setCount(1)
        if (phone)
            setCount(2)
        if (desktop)
            setCount(3)
    }

    const tablet = useMediaQuery({
        query: '(max-width:  876px)'
    })
    const phone = useMediaQuery({
        query: '(max-width:  576px)'
    })
    const desktop = useMediaQuery({
        query: '(min-width:  876px)'
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <Carousel slidesPerPage={count} >
            <img className="image-one"/>
            <img className="image-two"/>
            <img className="image-three"/>
            </Carousel>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `useEffect` has no dependencies so it loads one time only after the component has been mounted.
To fix that you should have the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Carousel from '@brainhubeu/react-carousel';
import '@brainhubeu/react-carousel/lib/style.css';
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive';

const MyCarousel = () => {

  const tablet = useMediaQuery({
    query: '(max-width:  876px)'
  });

  const phone = useMediaQuery({
    query: '(max-width:  576px)'
  });

  const desktop = useMediaQuery({
    query: '(min-width:  876px)'
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    loadMediaQuery();
  }, [tablet, phone, desktop]);

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const loadMediaQuery = () =>{
    if (tablet)
      setCount(1)
    else if (phone)
      setCount(2)
    else if (desktop)
      setCount(3)
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Carousel slidesPerPage={count} >
          <img className="image-one"/>
          <img className="image-two"/>
          <img className="image-three"/>
         </Carousel>
       </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` means: runs the callback function that's passed to `useEffect` after this component is rendered, and since you passed an empty array as the 2nd argument, it means `useEffect` is executed once, only the first time when this component gets rendered (and not when the state changes) , since your function call is inside useEffect, it will work only when you reload the page, you can either add the variables to the empty array like [Mohamed Magdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10926100/mohamed-magdy) did, or simply call `loadMediaQuery` again outside `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the custom hook provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19014495), you can do something like

```
const [width, height] = useWindowSize();

useEffect(() => {
  loadMediaQuery();
}, [width]);
```

That `useEffect` function says: Execute `loadMediaQuery()` every time the value of `width` changes.