# React to size change of another element

Tags: reactjs

If have two elements, then I can refer from one of those to the other using `useRef`.
The result of `useRef` is a reference to the element, lets call it `exampleRef`.

Is it possible to react to a size change of that element (e.g. on `exampleRef.current.offsetHeight`)?

I tried to use the following, which is unfortunately not firing when the referenced element is resized:

```
useEffect ( () => {
    // ... do something with exampleRef.current.offsetHeight
}, [exampleRef]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rerender view on browser resize with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014250/rerender-view-on-browser-resize-with-react)

Comment: no, unfortunately not because the element is not only resized because of a window resize event, but also because of a layout shift due to a collapsable menu. I changed the question - I fear it was a bit ambiguous

Comment: Use a ResizeObserver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39312522/996081

Comment: @cbr that's interesting! Thank you for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @cbr's comment the solution for my problem seems to be the so called `ResizeOberver` (which is, unfortunately, not supported by FirefoxMobile).

Anyway, here is a working example using a react module that is using the `ResizeObserver`:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-darwin-6bftu?file=/src/index.js

Another module that is using Hooks can be found here `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-resize-aware`