# useState not reflecting changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Clicking the button the div (simulates a sheet of paper should change orientation from vertical to horizontal.   What's the reason?  A state field depending on another field is not correct and due to the async nature, I get this unexpected result? Take into account this is a reduced example of my use case and I need both fields.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [verticalOrientation, setOrientation] = useState(true);
  const [dimensions] = useState(getDimensions(verticalOrientation));

  const style = {
    width: dimensions.width,
    height: dimensions.height,
    borderStyle: "solid",
  };
  console.log(verticalOrientation);
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      <h1>Sheet  of paper</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setOrientation(!verticalOrientation)}>
        Change orientation
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const getDimensions = (verticalOrientation) => {
  const proportion = verticalOrientation ? 16 / 9 : 9 / 16; // A4 vertical vs horizontal
  let width = 300;
  let height = proportion * width;
  console.log(height, proportion, verticalOrientation);

  return { width, height };
};
```

[See code running in Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-resonance-ok2zk?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 3):

`dimensions` should not be stateful, because it doesn't have a state setter that is ever called - it only depends on the *other* stateful value of `verticalOrientation`. So `dimensions` should just be an ordinary variable declared locally in the component. (You could wrap it in a `useMemo` if you wanted)

```
export default function App() {
  const [verticalOrientation, setOrientation] = useState(true);
  const dimensions = getDimensions(verticalOrientation);
  // ...
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const [verticalOrientation, setOrientation] = React.useState(true);
  const dimensions = getDimensions(verticalOrientation);

  const style = {
    width: dimensions.width,
    height: dimensions.height,
    borderStyle: "solid",
  };
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      <h1>Sheet  of paper</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setOrientation(!verticalOrientation)}>
        Change orientation
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const getDimensions = (verticalOrientation) => {
  const proportion = verticalOrientation ? 16 / 9 : 9 / 16; // A4 vertical vs horizontal
  let width = 300;
  let height = proportion * width;

  return { width, height };
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: In the real case I'm using a settter for dimensions in case user resize window I upgrade dimensions state field to force a render.

Comment: In an effect hook with an empty dependency array, you can add a resize listener to the window that sets state, where the `getDimensions` calculations take the values from that state to figure out what gets returned. Eg instead of `window.innerWidth -> getDimensions` you could have `useEffect` -> `setWidth(window.innerWidth)` -> `getDimensions(width)` Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19014495

Comment: Yes I do like that and works ok on resize. However not when. i click button as in my reduced code above.