# Trying to set window height but it gives an error in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, use-state

I use useState to get the window height but it gives a runtime error saying that window is not defined. Do you know why

Here's the code:

```
let [winHeight,setWinHeight] = useState(window.innerHeight)
```

```
useEffect(() => {
          const list = []
          for (var i=0;i<datas.length;i++){
               const t = datas[i].title
               const res = handleResize(i + 2)
               list.push(<li ref={resl[i + 1]} style={{top: "20px",left: res + "px"}}><Anchor href={datas[i].link || `/${t.replace(/ /g, "_")}`}><a onClick={() => closeNav()} onMouseOver={() => setHovering(i)}>{t}</a></Anchor></li>)
          }
          setWinHeight(window.innerHeight)
          setLinks(list)
     }, [winHeight])
```

Comment: Try passing it inside the dependency array

Comment: I've changed the question, sorry for that

Comment: You want to take a look at this other answer, it should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19014495/5460827

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-framework-1y87c?file=/src/App.js:0-530

Comment: I would suggest checking this out: https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding window.height in useEffect's dependency array?

```
useEffect(() => {
      const list = []
      for (var i=0;i<datas.length;i++){
           const t = datas[i].title
           const res = handleResize(i + 2)
           list.push(<li ref={resl[i + 1]} style={{top: "20px",left: res + "px"}}><Anchor href={datas[i].link || `/${t.replace(/ /g, "_")}`}><a onClick={() => closeNav()} onMouseOver={() => setHovering(i)}>{t}</a></Anchor></li>)
      }
      setLinks(list)
 }, [window.innerHeight])
```

Comment: tried it but it gives another error saying that window is not defined

Comment: tried calling it with useState but nothing did change at all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19014495/11038519 you can try this solution

Comment: now my code does work, but the only thing that is left to do is to make it run initially. Since it only runs the code inside the useEffect hook when the window.innerHeight does change, it does not run initially

Comment: Did it by calling the initial value with a returning function, thanks a lot for your help. I'm verifying this response

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let [winHeight,setWinHeight] = useState(0)

useEffect(()=> {
setWinHeight(window.innerHeight)
},[])
```

And also you need to import useEffect from 'react'.

window isn't defined because the component isn't renderer at the point you are trying to access window object.

Comment: Now I don't get the error, but my code inside the useEffect doesn't work. I'm updating the quistion now so you'll get what I mean.

Comment: here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hx1snp?file=index.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on RN? Then you can try this to get the height~

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

---

*Last Post*

Add the `resize` [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event)

Following this one, it would update the `winHeight` when you change height of window

```
  const lastHeight = useRef(window.innerHeight);

  const [winHeight, setWinHeight] = useState(lastHeight.current);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
      const curHeight = e.currentTarget?.innerHeight;
      if (lastHeight.current !== curHeight) {
        lastHeight.current = curHeight;
        setWinHeight(curHeight);
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Window itself is undefined, so nothing can be called that contains the window object

Comment: so resizing does not work

Answer (score 0):

use [window.innerHeight] not [winHeight]  inside dependency Array of UseEffect