# how do i render component based on width screen?

Tags: reactjs

// import { useState } from 'react'
import Res from './responsiveMenu/Res'
import NormalWidth from './navNormalwidth/NormalWidth'

const Navbar=()=>{
const [click,setClick]=useState(true)

// function to change from true to false
const navBtn=()=>{setClick(!click)}

```
const screenwidth=window.innerWidth

return(

<>
{screenwidth<'640' ? <Res btnF={navBtn} click={click}/>:screenwidth>'640'?<NormalWidth/>:''}
  
</>

)
```

}

export default Navbar

why when the screen is 640 is works but when i make it bigger i  the menu btn stays until i press it  then it will render the normal component

Comment: You would need to either listen for the window resize event, or use a ResizeObserver. Then update the width variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rerender view on browser resize with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014250/rerender-view-on-browser-resize-with-react)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your component does NOT rerender when the window size is changing. You need to register a listener, which updates the a react `state` which causes your component to rerender.
State of the art would be to create this via a hook. As this is a very common functionality people already implemented examples of such a hook for you.

You can find a good one here. Not library needed.

https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/

If you are not yet familiar with using hooks, the official React documentation is very good.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use the viewport unit with width.

eg:

```
width:100vw;
```

Comment: This is used for styling with css. But in the shared code he wants to conditionally render a different button based on the current window width. So he either needs to use css `media queries` to hide or show the button via css or as mentioned in my answer observe the window width to cause rerendering of the component.