# Highcharts charts don't resize properly on window resize

Tags: highcharts

I have 2 side-by-side charts on my page, and would like to have them resized when window is resized: their container is set to 50% width, which, according to examples, should be enough.

A working example of automatically resizing chart can be found @ http://jsfiddle.net/2gtpA/

A non-working example I did to reproduce the issue can be seen @ http://jsfiddle.net/4rrZw/2/

**NOTE**: you have to resize the frame several times to reproduce the issue (smaller>bigger>smaller should do)

I think it all lies in the way you declare containers... pasting the HTML code as the JS code for highcharts doesn't seem to be relevant here... (same in both examples)

```
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50%;">
        <div id="container" style="height: 50%"></div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:50%;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I forked your fiddle to a working solution @ http://jsfiddle.net/AxyNp/
The most important code snippet from there is this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    height = chart.height
    width = $("#chartRow").width() / 2
    chart.setSize(width, height, doAnimation = true);
});
```

The solution bears on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768565/resize-height-with-highcharts) SO post's answer.

It seems like the best you can do to resize the chart's container (and cell) properly is to rely on your own resize trigger. Note that I set the reflow to "false" in the chart's options to remove the existing trigger.

Answer (score 23):

You can avoid using javascript to perform the resize and rely on css instead.  This can be accomplished by rendering the HighChart into a div that has:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

To make sure that the height of the container is appropriate, you'll have to wrap this absolutely positioned element in another element that has explicitly set height:

```
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
```

By rendering the HighChart into a position absolute element, the chart will be responsive to width reductions in the parent.

Comment: THANK YOU! This solves https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6427 where highcharts doesn't resize properly inside a flex container.

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * Adjust size for hidden charts
 * @param chart highcharts
 */
function adjustGraph(chart) {
    try {
        if (typeof (chart === 'undefined' || chart === null) && this instanceof jQuery) { // if no obj chart and the context is set
            this.find('.chart-container:visible').each(function () { // for only visible charts container in the curent context
                $container = $(this); // context container
                $container.find('div[id^="chart-"]').each(function () { // for only chart
                    $chart = $(this).highcharts(); // cast from JQuery to highcharts obj
                    $chart.setSize($container.width(), $chart.chartHeight, doAnimation = true); // adjust chart size with animation transition
                });
            });
        } else {
            chart.setSize($('.chart-container:visible').width(), chart.chartHeight, doAnimation = true); // if chart is set, adjust
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if (this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
    this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function () {
        // resizeEnd call function with pass context body
        adjustGraph.call($('body'));
    }, 500);
});
```

### For bootstrap tab

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    isChart = $(this).attr('data-chart');
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    if (isChart) {
        // call functio inside context target
        adjustGraph.call($(target));
    }
});


<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active">
         <a href="#anagrafica" data-toggle="tab"><h5>Anagrafica</h5></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#consumi" data-toggle="tab" data-chart="1"><h5>Consumi</h5></a></li>
</ul>
```

### On chart

```
    new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart-bar',
                defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                zoomType: 'xy',
                backgroundColor: null,
                events: {
                    load: function (event) {
                        adjustGraph(this);
                    }
                }
            },
```

### Html code

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="charts">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner chart-container">
                    <div class="active item">
                        <h3>Chart 1/h3>
                        <div id="bar-pod-annuale">
                           <div id="chart-bar" style="width:100%;margin: 0 auto"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h3>Char 2</h3>
                        /** chart **/
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h3>Char 3</h3>
                        /** chart **/
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Carousel nav -->
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### See example on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/davide_vallicella/LuxFd/2/