# Highcharter is NOT automatically resize output in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, r-highcharter

The **development-version** of highcharter package has the following issue:

highchartOutput **DOES NOT automatically resize the width** of the plot **when hiding the sidebar** in shinydashboard. The width of the plot always remains same.

I provide an example here,

```
# install development-version of highcharter
# devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")

library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(
      width = 12,
      highchartOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderHighchart({
    highcharts_demo()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: sidebar is shown]

[image: sidebar is hidden]

I have tried

```
$(document).on("click", ".sidebar-toggle", function() { $(window).trigger("resize"); });
```

BUT it still does not work for development-version highcharter when I use `renderHighchart` & `highchartOutput` functions.

However, I found

- `renderHighchart2` and `highchartOutput2` working well for resizing.
- BUT `renderHighchart2` and `highchartOutput2` DO NOT support heatmap, I still need to use `renderHighchart` and `highchartOutput` to get correlation plot.

ANY suggestions for this resizing problem?

Comment: Above code works fine for me.I'm on R version `3.6.1`, `highcharter_0.7.0`  `shiny_1.4.0` and  `shinydashboard_0.7.1`

Comment: Also works for me: R 4.0.0, `highcharter_0.7.0`, `shiny_1.4.0.2` and `shinydashboard_0.7.1`

Comment: As I mention above, the development-version of highcharter will cause the issue. Specifically, highcharter version 0.7.0.9001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I got the solution. In the development-version `highcharter`, fix the code in `highcharter.js` file as following:

```
/* fix bug here */
 resize: function(el, width, height, instance) {

   /* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445784/ */
   var chart = $("#" +el.id).highcharts();
   var height = chart.renderTo.clientHeight; 
   var width = chart.renderTo.clientWidth; 
   chart.setSize(width, height); 

 }
```

Then the automatic resizing will work appropriately.