# modified the css of a graph

Tags: css, angular

I don't understand why my compose `graphic.html` is so big.

I have placed my highcharts object in a `"graphic"` div.

```
    <div class="graphic">
        <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions"
        style="height: 150px; width: 900px; "></highcharts-chart>
   </div>
```

On the css side I have this:

```
.graphic{
    display: block;
    max-width: 900px;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

Except that the result is not there!
Do you have an idea why the size of the graphic is not suitable?

Comment: Create a reproducible demo so that we can look into the issue.

Comment: Ok no worries but with which software would you like a demo?

Comment: Try https://codesandbox.io/s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have already initialized the options object which you have named **chartOptions**, there you should have specified the type of chart you want to be rendered.

In that object only you have to specify the height and width of the chart that you want.
So your chartOptions should have the following the properties:

```
chartOptions:any={
 chart: {
  type: 'scatter',
  height: 150,
  width:900
},
```

}

Comment: Yes, I just realized this solution

Answer (score 0):

It's always challenging to render High Charts in a Div which is having it's own CSS.

If we want to do that.. we need start applying those styles directly on the chart object itself. Have you seen these below links..

https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40607

[Resize height with Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768565/resize-height-with-highcharts)

You can also read more about this in the official documentation.    ***[`Reflow - HighCharts`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow)***

Comment: i can't vote (i need reputation) :/ but i accept the answer