# Auto chart height

Tags: highcharts

The default highstock chart has height = 400px.

How can height chart be set for auto size based on chart axis and its sizes ?

See the example bellow, the navigation bar is over the volume panel.

http://jsfiddle.net/BYNsJ/

I know that I can set the height for the div but I have a solution that insert/remove axis/series dynamically in the chart and would be nice an auto height chart.

The example is the same Candlestick/Volume demo from Highchart site, but without height property in the div container.

```
    // split the data set into ohlc and volume
    var ohlc = [],
        volume = [],
        dataLength = data.length;

    for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        ohlc.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][1], // open
            data[i][2], // high
            data[i][3], // low
            data[i][4] // close
        ]);

        volume.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][5] // the volume
        ])
    }

    // set the allowed units for data grouping
    var groupingUnits = [[
        'week',                         // unit name
        [1]                             // allowed multiples
    ], [
        'month',
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
    ]];

    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Historical'
        },

        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: 200,
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: 300,
            height: 100,
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }],

        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: ohlc,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }]
    });
    });
});
```

Regards.

Comment: You should be able to use percents in your yAxes instead of fixed value: http://jsfiddle.net/BYNsJ/13/ if it will not help you with this problem, you can use chart.setSize() for setting the correct height of your chart;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts - how to have a chart with dynamic height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809852/highcharts-how-to-have-a-chart-with-dynamic-height)

Answer (score 2):

here is one example which is resize chart according screen.
http://jsfiddle.net/davide_vallicella/LuxFd/2/

Just don't set the height property in HighCharts and it will handle it dynamically for you so long as you set a height on the chart's containing element. It can be a fixed number or a even a percent if position is absolute.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height

By default the height is calculated from the offset height of the containing element

find example here:- http://jsfiddle.net/wkkAd/149/

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hey I was using angular 2+ and highchart/highstock v.5, I think it will work in JS or jQuery also, here is a easy solution

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <chart type="StockChart" [options]="stockValueOptions"></chart> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
   height: 90%;
}
```

TS

```
 this.stockValueOptions = {
     chart: {
         renderTo: 'container'                    
     },
     yAxis: [{
        height: '60%'
     },{
        top: '65%',
        height: '35%'
     }]
}
```

Its working, and a easy one. Remove chart height add height in '%' for the yAxis.

Comment: Using `renderTo` made it work for me, and it's the most elegant solution in among the others here IMO

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts does not support dynamic height, you can achieve it by `$(window).resize` event:

```
$(window).resize(function() 
{    
    chart.setSize(
       $(document).width(), 
       $(document).height()/2,
       false
    );   
});
```

See demo fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vCZ8V/1/).

Comment: I think you need to include  http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js in your example to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set chart.height dynamically with chart.update method.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update

```
function resizeChartFromValues (chart) {
  const pixelsForValue = 10
  const axis = chart.yAxis[0]
  chart.update({ chart: { height: (axis.max - axis.min) * pixelsForValue } })
}

const options = {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load () {resizeChartFromValues(this)}
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [30, 70, 100],
  }]
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options)

setTimeout(() => {
  chart.series[0].setData([10, 20, 30])
  resizeChartFromValues(chart)
}, 1000)
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/a97fgsmc/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:absolute"></div>
```

No special options to the chart. The chart fits perfect to the browser even if I resize it.