# Highcharts Bar Chart Auto Height

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts 3d Bar chart and I need the height to automatically size depending on how many bars are on the chart. We may only need 1 or we may need 100. the current problem is that it always expands to fill the page. So If I have one it will be a huge bar and if I have 100 it will be all smashed together. I need it to grow as it has data.

I have done searching and see this http://jsfiddle.net/wkkAd/149/ demo.

Here is my chart with that demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a40a0bjy/2/

The issue is that I neeed to to grow as it has more bars. Right now, it expands to 100% of my page height.

I set the bar height hoping that it would stop the chart from growing bigger but it does not work.

Using:

```
 pointWidth: 30//width of the column bars irrespective of the chart size
```

If I do that, it will just have the 30 width bars with all kinds of space and the chart still expands to fill the entire page height.

**Update:** This is what I want to do. http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/jMX8G/ 
If you remove some of that data the charts automatically is smaller, while keeping the same size bar heights.

This issue with that demo is that my data is much more complex than that demos. Here it is:

```
var data = [{
            name: 'Not Complete',
            data: [{
                y: 5,
                drilldown: {
                TaskID: 343434545252,
                name: 'somename'
                }

            },
            {
                y: 3,
                drilldown: {
                TaskID: 343434545252,
                name: 'somename'
            }
        },
        {
               y: 4,
               drilldown: {
               TaskID: 343434545252,
               name: 'somename'
            }
        },
        {
               y: 7,
               drilldown: {
               TaskID: 343434545252,
               name: 'somename'
            }
        },
       {
              y: 2,
              drilldown: {
              TaskID: 343434545252,
              name: 'somename'
           }
       }]
    }, {
        name: 'Clean Up',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Complete',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }];
```

Now the denmo uses this:

```
 height: data.length * 20 + 120 // 20px per data item plus top and bottom margins
```

But I do not know how or what to get the length of for my data.

Comment: you need to do some pre-processing. however/wherever you are pulling and formatting your data, you should be able to count the number of bars to be generated, and pass that to the chart or function that determines the height of the containing element

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried in my updated answer, but I dont know how to access the length with the way I have to format my code.

Comment: It depends on how you are building your data array in the first place.

Comment: i figured it out, as I looped through to build the above data. I started with 400px and then added 50px for each bar that is added to data.