# Can I have a chart automatically size the height (rather than using 400px) using the Highcharts .NET Wrapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

There is another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809852/highcharts-how-to-have-a-chart-with-dynamic-height), but that seems to be focused on the js library, not Highsoft.Highcharts (and I'm using v8.1.1.1) I tried some of these solutions, but they didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use those CSS options:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant when you're working with a .NET wrapper, but this seemed to work (from a colleague of mine). When using the wrapper, "chart" comes from the Id of the Highcharts object. So you will need to change that if you use something else for Id.

```
var chart = new Highcharts { Id = "chart" };
```

And then this script in the .cshtml file:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        // "chart" is the Id of the Highcharts container
        var chart = $('#chart').highcharts();
        var width = $('#chart').width();
        // 100 is an approximation for the hight of the navbar + margin for panel. Removing that from the entire height of the window.
        var height = $(window).innerHeight() - 100;
        $('panel-body').height = height;
        // setsize will trigger the graph redraw 
        chart.setSize(width, height, false);
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        // "chart" is the Id of the Highcharts container
        var chart = $('#chart').highcharts();
        var width = $('#chart').width();
        // 100 is an approximation for the hight of the navbar + margin for panel. Removing that from the entire height of the window.
        var height = $(window).innerHeight() - 100;
        // setsize will trigger the graph redraw 
        chart.setSize(width, height, false);
    });
</script>
```