# Highcharts automatic resize using drag/resize react-rnd library

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I want to create a component where the size of the chart automatically adjusts with resize events of the container holding the graph. It would be great if someone can help me with an example. Here si the link to the library. [react-rnd library](https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd)

E.x somehting like this but using highcharts [codebox react-rnd with googlecharts](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3zr91ok73?file=/src/index.js)

```
const Highchart = () => {
 
return (

<rnd>
<div>
<HightchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} constructorType={'chart'} options={option} /> 
</div>
</rnd>
)
}
```

Comment: This question would help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809852/highcharts-how-to-have-a-chart-with-dynamic-height

Comment: Highchart by default adjust to the container. Set width property under chart option to 100%, so it takes the size of the container.

Comment: The problem I run into is that I need to resize bowser for the affects to appear. Any idea why ?

Comment: In that case query for body tag, take clientWidth and update this value with the chart width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `chart.reflow` method in `onResizeStop` event callback function.

```
return (
  <Rnd
    ...
    onResizeStop={(e, direction, ref, delta, position) => {
      const chart = this.chartComponent.current?.chart;
      if (chart) {
        chart.reflow();
      }
      ...
    }}
  >
    ...
  </Rnd>
);
```

From Highcharts API:

> **reflow( [e])**
>
> Reflows the chart to its container. By default, the chart reflows
> automatically to its container following a window.resize event, as per
> the chart.reflow option. However, there are no reliable events for div
> resize, so if the container is resized without a window resize event,
> this must be called explicitly.

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-hoover-cz-czw5k?file=/src/index.js

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow

Comment: Waw!! Amazing answer. I'll post a functional component edition. You're awesome :)